# Hide an image set in storyboard for a particular condition in ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an image which I have put i storyboard but I need to hide it for a particular user. I am not sure how to do it in the code. I ll share what I have done:

in controller.h I write:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *downArrowImage;
```

In controller.m

I put my if condition and inside it , I do this:

```
 [self.downArrowImage setHidden:NO];
```

This I do in intializeView but iut doesnt work, any suggestions?
My image name is DownArrowImage. I am not sure how the linking between image and the variable downArrowImage takes place.

Answer (score 0):

User this code.

```
imageVIew.isHidden = true
```

or

```
height.constant = 0
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageVIew: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var height: NSLayoutConstraint!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //height.constant = 0
        imageVIew.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

[image]

Second screenshot.

[image]

Comment: How is the linkling taking place here? I want to hide a particular image. Name of the image is DownArrowImage.png.It is set inside storyboard

Comment: see the second screenshot example